# How to use AND operator in IF statements in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I am new to SML.
How do I use the AND operator inside IF statements?
Here is my code:

```
val y = 1;
val x = 2;
if (x = 1 AND y = 2) then print ("YES ") else print("NO ");
```

My error is:
stdIn:66.9-67.3 Error: unbound variable or constructor: AND
stdIn:66.3-67.9 Error: operator is not a function [literal]
  operator: int
  in expression:
    1 
stdIn:66.3-67.9 Error: operator and operand don't agree [literal]
  operator domain: bool * bool
  operand:         bool * int
  in expression:
    x = (1 ) y = 2

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no `AND` operator in SML (unless you define one yourself). There is an `and` keyword, but you can't use it inside `if` statements (or generally as a part of any expression) because it's not an operator. It's used in combination with `fun` to define mutually recursive functions.

You're probably looking for the `andalso` operator, which takes two boolean operands and returns true if and only if both operands are true.

Answer (score 1):

May I disagree with Vishal's comment?

```
*-true andalso true ;     
val it = false : bool
-true andalso false ;  
val it = false : bool*
```

I *think* (and so does the REPL) that

> *true andalso true ;*

evaluates to true, not false

Answer (score -1):

here is an example which will clear the usage of andalso

```
-true andalso true ;
val it = false : bool
- true andalso false ; 
val it = false : bool
```

Answer (score -1):

one and one in digital gates is always 1; therefore
in the above case true andalso true "must necessarily evaluate to true , not false; am'i correct ?
also 1 and 0 can't never be 1;

1 or 0 can be 1;